# Return a distance matrix containing vectors

Tags: python

I am trying to calculate a distance matrix, but from vectors so I want to return a distance matrix where `(i, j)` is the distance between two vectors, e.g. between `a` and `b`. So I wish to create for example in this case a 4x4 matrix that contain a vector in each position. Here are my sample arrays, each contain a vector with multiple points.

```
a = [a1, a2, a3]

b = [b1, b2, b3]

c = [c1, c2, c3]
```

I tried using the `scipy.spatial.distance.pdist` and `squareform` (which just gives me a full instead of condensed matrix), but it returns me single values instead of vectors.

So a matrix like this,

```
[ 0 1 2        

  1 0 2 

  2 3 0 ]
```

Instead of this, where each `i, j` position is the distance between two vectors therefore contains 5 points as per the example.

```
[ [a1/a1, a2/a2, a3/a3 ] [a1/b1, a2/b2, a3/b3] [a1/c1, a2/c2, a3/c3] 

[b1/a1, b2/a2, b3/a3] [b1/b1, b2/b2, b3/b3] [b1/c1, b2/c2, b3/c3] 

[c1/a1, c2/a2, c3/a3] [c1/b1, c2/b2, c3/b3] [c1/c1, c2/c2, c3/c3]]
```

I want to calculate the distance of each value in the array individually, so I do not wish to calculate the Eucladian distance of a1, a2, a3 against b1, b2, b3 but rather just a1 against b1 and so on... I want to return a vector that includes the distance calculated between all the values of array a and b and position it at (a,b). By the '/' I want to show between which two values the distance should be calculated.

Comment: What precisely is the vectorial measure of the distance between two vectors that you have in mind?

Comment: @ReblochonMasque If I understood correctly, I am calculating the Euclidean distance between two vectors

Comment: Yes, but how is the euclidian distance between vectors calculated? How is it a vector?

Comment: @ReblochonMasque I apologize I was using vector and array interchangeably...For example taking array **a** and **b**, the distance between x1 from a and x1 from b and so on. So each point in this array should be calculated and I want to return that array for position (a,b) in my matrix

Comment: x1 is a coordinate vector? for instance `x1 = (2.345, 4.984, -1.772)`?

Comment: @ReblochonMasque No x1 is a single value, so array **a** = (0.1, 0.2, 0.4, 0.1, 0.5 ) for example

Comment: @ReblochonMasque I want to calculate distance between array a and b for each value (so for x1, x2, x3, x4, x5) and return that calculated array as postion (a,b) in my matrix

Comment: Give a simple and clear example, it's pretty confusing. Give us an example of inputs and the corresponding output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand, you're asking for a per-element distance (absolute value ?) such that the "distance" between two lists is also a list.
Here is my little example

```
vec = [[1, 2, 3], #a
       [4, 5, 6], #b
       [7, 8, 9]] #c
#oneliner
mat = [[[abs(vec[i][k] - vec[j][k] for k in len(vec[i]))]
                                   for j in len(vec)]
                                   for i in len(vec)]
```

which outputs :

```
mat
[[[0, 0, 0], [3, 3, 3], [6, 6, 6]], 
 [[3, 3, 3], [0, 0, 0], [3, 3, 3]], 
 [[6, 6, 6], [3, 3, 3], [0, 0, 0]]]
```

and because the result is symmetrical, we can compute only the first half of the matrix :

```
mat = [[[abs(vec[i][k] - vec[j][k]) for k in range(len(vec[i]))] 
                                    if i<j else [] 
                                    for j in range(len(vec))]
                                    for i in range(len(vec))]
```

which will output somthing like this :

```
mat
[[[], [3, 3, 3], [6, 6, 6]], 
 [[], [],        [3, 3, 3]], 
 [[], [],        []]]
```

Comment: Yes, that is what I am attempting to do. My matrix will be much larger, so I will try to create a for loop. Thank you! @pLOPeGG